# Performing a fuzzy contains check

Tags: java, lucene, levenshtein-distance, keyword-search, fuzzywuzzy

I would like to check if a keyword string is contained within a text string. This must be a fuzzy contains.

My first attempt was to use the library [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/xdrop/fuzzywuzzy). This seemed to have unexpected behavior producing high match values when the strings differed quite a lot when using the partial ratio.

I've tried using levenshtein's distance which works for comparing one string to another but not for finding if a string contains a keyword.
One idea I tried was to split the text into individual words and then loop through them all calculating the distance to see if there is a match. The problem is that the keyword may have white space in it which means it wouldn't find any matches using this method.

I've now tried using a Bitap algorithm to find if the keyword is in the text but this come back as true when the keyword and text are very different. The algorithm can be found [here.](https://github.com/masonmlai/bitap/blob/master/src/bitap/Bitap.java#L210)

```
final String keyword = "br0wn foxes very nice and hfhjdfgdfgdfgfvffdbdffgjfjfhjgjfdghfghghfg".toLowerCase();
final String text = "The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over the Lazy Dog".toLowerCase();

final Bitap bitap = new Bitap(keyword, alphabet);   
bitap.within(text, 20);    // Returns true
```

I've looked into using Lucene. The problem with this is that a lot of it is based around creating indexes from all the data and then performing the search. In my case this can't be done as it needs to be a method that takes a keyword and text separately. If there are any resources to do with performing a fuzzy contains without indexing using Lucene it would be very useful.

What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem a while ago.
The requirement was that incoming texts that contained url's that are registered as blocked in the system should be detected and removed.

However they wouldn't match 100% because the detection of the incoming texts was done through an OCR algorithm.

Let's say we have a String that is blocked "www.blockedwebsite.com" and an incoming String that is "I like the website www.blockdwebsite.com :)" (notice the 'e' was removed from the url). Calculating the levenshtein distance would result in a big distance because of the 'I like the website ', so no match.
(I use the apache.commons.similarity.LevenshteinDistance library)

What I did was I iterated over the incoming String, taking the substring from i to the length of the blocked String.

```
    LevenshteinDistance ld = LevenshteinDistance.getDefaultInstance();
    String incomingString = "I like the website www.blockdwebsite.com";
    String blockedString = "www.blockedwebsite.com";
    for (int i = 0; i < incomingString.length()-blockedString.length(); i++) {
        String substring = incomingString.substring(i, i+blockedString.length());
        Integer distance = ld.apply(substring, blockedString);
        if (distance < 5)
            System.out.println("match found");
    }
```

When the distance drops below 5 a match has been detected. You can alter this to be a 90% match or something like that.
I hope this helps. Good luck.